# process in GCP VM instance killed automatically

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, process, signals

I'm using GCP VM instance for running my python script as back ground process.

But I found my script got SIGTERM.

I check the syslog and daemon.log in /var/log
and I found my python script (2316) was terminated by system.

What do I need to check VM settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you run your process in background?

Comment: I tried with both nohup option and screen command.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this log line in your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hVUz.png):

> Nov 12 18:23:10 ai-task-1 systemd-logind[1051]: Power key pressed.

I would say that your script's process was `SIGTERM`ed as a result of the hypervisor gracefully shutting down the VM, which would happen when a GCP user or service account with admin access to the project performs a GCE [compute.instances.stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) request.

You can look for this request's logs for more details on where it comes from in the Logs [Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)/[Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) or `gcloud logging read --freshness=30d` ([man](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read)) with some filters like:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
"ai-task-1"
timestamp>="2020-11-12T18:22:40Z"
timestamp<="2020-11-12T18:23:40Z"
```

Though depending on the retention period for your `_Default` [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#custom-retention) (30 days [by default](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods)), these logs may have already expired.